# Can't connect to localhost on my application server but can access it via web

Tags: web, server, localhost

I have a website which is accessible via its URL but strangely i cannot connect to it via localhost on the server itself.

- I have ensured that "127.0.0.1    localhost" is in my hosts file
- I have checked that no other application is using port 80
- I've ticked "Bypass Proxy Server for local addresses"
- Pinging my local host from  command line returns data When you go to the domain host URL the  application loads successfully

Good news is my site is fully functioning but i just cannot figure out how to connect to it on localhost in my browser! any ideas?

Added details as requested;

- Its a website not app if that was misleading.
- The webserver is IIS on an Amazon EC2 windows instance.
- The root URL is just a simple html page, which i can access via the domain URL.
- However when i RDP onto the Server itself and try to access the localhost, it continually blocks me, the page wont load.

Comment: important information is missing, for example operating system, programming language, web server stack and so on. What does "*web application which is accessible via web*" mean exactly? That the app is public? If it is public how can it be local too?

Comment: i've added some more details

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your application is only listening on external IP address. To bind your application on all IP address, you may make your application listen on 0.0.0.0.

And could you please show the related code to help locating the problem?